# Why does my Android Webview app with a Hls.js video player freezes after 3-4 hours?

Tags: android, html5-video, android-webview, svelte, hls.js

Im at the breaking point with this error. I developed a svelte webapp with an `hls.js` video player which I packaged in an android webview for Firesticks. The App works great except for one odd issue where after about 3-4 hours of playback the video freezes. I was able to catch some logs using `adb`.

[image]

The error does not happen in the usual `hls.js` `onError` handlers, but instead is being generated elsewhere. `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'byteLength')` is totally ambiguous but it is the best I've been able to get. **Unfortunately the error only happens on the actual minified JS code and not on any browser debug builds.**

Im at a total loss as to what could be causing this or how to even debug it. Maybe someone has experienced something like this in the past? Below is the video element in my svelte component and the `hls.js` initialization code.

```html
<div class="playback-view" on:click|stopPropagation>
    <video
        bind:this={videoRef}
        bind:currentTime={$ProgramTime}
        on:ended={onPlaybackEnded}
        bind:duration
        bind:paused>
        <track kind="captions">
    </video>
```

```js
    const destroyHls = () => {
        if (hls !== null && hls !== undefined){
            hls.stopLoad()
            hls.detachMedia()
            hls.destroy()
        }        
    }

    const reloadSource = () => {
        destroyHls()
        if (videoRef !== null && videoRef !== undefined){
            hls = new Hls({
                // Audio codec for bitrate above 22hz
                defaultAudioCodec: "mp4a.40.2",
                //(seconds) If buffer < this value fragment will be loaded
                // The "minimum" length of the buffer
                maxBufferLength: 15,
                backBufferLength: 1800,
                // (seconds) The maximum length of the buffer
                maxMaxBufferLength: 60,
                // (bytes) The amount hls will try to load
                // maxBufferSize: 120 * 1000 * 1000,
                // (seconds) The amount to offset the stream by when stalling
                // currentTime += (nb nudge retry -1)*nudgeOffset
                nudgeOffset: 0.1,
                // Number of nudges before BUFFER_STALLED_ERROR
                nudgeMaxRetry: 3,
            })
            hls.attachMedia(videoRef)
            hls.loadSource($Playback.playbackUrl)
            hls.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, handleHLSError)
            videoRef.play()
            paused = false
        }
    }
```

After a comment suggested to check the buffer size. I decreased the backBufferLength and the maxMaxBufferLength. Now however I am faced with a new error.

```json
"hlsError" {"type":"mediaError","parent":"main","details":"bufferAppendError","err":{"stack":"Error: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The HTMLMediaElement.error attribute is not null.
```

This is failing to append to source buffer, but shouldn't `hls.js` be taking care of the clearing the buffer?

Comment: My guess would be that Android is killing the web worker which might communicate via an `ArrayBuffer` (which would have a `byteLength` property). Would check for how memory usage develops, in case there is a memory leak which causes a forced shutdown after extended play time.

Comment: @H.B. Thank you very much for your suggestion, It seems that it helped something because no I am faced with something totally new. Maybe you have an idea here as well?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the value of the mentioned `error` property of the media element. It probably prevents adding to the buffer while in an error state.

Comment: @Aleksandr Don't know why, might be a buffering issue. Maybe HLS.js keeps the bytes in memory (for rewinding) and your system gives up after 3-4 hours. Possible **solution*: Every hour just close the connection and immediately reload the link. It should carry on the livestream but with cleared buffers. There might be a command to "flush the buffer" without a disconnect.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One thats not a bad idea. Ive been playing with `backBufferLength`. Setting it to 900 has seemed to help, but not sure totally confident yet. If it doesn't help I think I'll implement something like what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was unable to figure out a consistently working set of settings for this issue. Changing HLS options simply resulted in different errors happening. In the end I basically did something similar to what @VC.One suggested.

I used the `onerror` methods of `hls.js` to detect `fragLoadError` and when it shows up I do a reload of the stream at that specific time. This means calling `reloadSource` as defined in the original question.

I don't feel amazing about this solution since it is only a bandaid, but it works rather reliably. At most you will get a 5 second freeze in the video playback every couple of hours.